# How to access PHP defined constant in javascript of twig?

Tags: javascript, php, twig, constants, silex

I have `constants.php` file autoloaded using composer in Silex.

constants.php

```
<?php
define('SENT_SUCCESS_','Chat Transcript has been successfully sent');
define('INVALID_CASE_NUMBER','Invalid Case Number');
define('INVALID_FILE_EXTENSIONS','Following attachment(s) couldn\'t be uploaded with this chat due to an Invalid Extensions');
?>
```

I want to access it in my `index.html.twig` file in js `<script />` tag.
We can easily use php variable in js but I don't have idea, how to use php constant.
I tried this but not working in `index.html.twig`.

```
<script>
const INVALID = '{{INVALID_FILE_EXTENSIONS}}';
</script>
```

Anyone have idea, how to get this variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the function [constant](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/constant.html) as seen on the documentation

```
<script>
const INVALID = '{{ constant('INVALID_FILE_EXTENSIONS') }}';
</script>
```

Comment: oh crap, I tried ```'{{ constant(INVALID_FILE_EXTENSIONS) }}';```, inverted comma's make much difference.

Comment: Remember that the `twig` part is executed before reaching the browser, thus creating a valid javascript syntax